# Custom Logger Provider being excluded by Serilog

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, serilog

Serilog works great, but I noticed it seems to exclude any custom logger providers I setup.

When I have `UseSerilog()` in my Startup, my CustomProvider never gets created (`CreateLogger` never gets called).

Is it possible to still use custom providers with Serilog?

```
//class Program, Main Method
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseConfiguration(config)
    .UseSerilog() //after adding this, my Custom Logger never gets called 
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();


//class Startup
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory logger, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    logger.AddProvider(new CustomProvider(serviceProvider));
}

public class CustomProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public CustomProvider(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    //--------------never gets called---------------
    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        var logger = _serviceProvider.GetService<CustomLogger>();
        logger.LogLevel = LogLevel.Error;

        return logger;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am am struggling with the same issue. Could you please share how you solved the issue with a concrete example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to plug your custom provider into Serilog (as a sink) instead. Serilog replaces the entire default logging pipeline for greater efficiency and so that there aren't two sets of level controls and filters to keep in sync.

This post has the background: https://nblumhardt.com/2017/08/use-serilog/.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have an resources about integrating ASP.NET Core dependency injection with a Custom Serilog sink? I'd like to inject some services into my sink.

Comment: You're welcome. Nothing on hand, but I'd guess someone out there will have a recipe, somewhere - all the best!